# BluePrism count number of times a character exists in a string

Tags: blueprism

I have a calculation which will remove a blank space and replace with a full stop. This is correct for 90% of my cases. However, sometimes two blanks will appear in my value. For the second space I want to delete it. Is this possible?
I think it may be possible using a code stage, but I am not sure what the code would be.

My current calculation is Replace([Item Data.Name], " ", ".")

Example data John B Smith I want the result to be John.BSmith

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this issue by using the Utility - Strings object and the split text action. I split my name by space. This outputted a collection which I was then able to loop through and add a full stop after the fist instance but then trim the other instances.

Please see screenshot

[image]

Answer (score 2):

For anything that'd like to do with the strings, there is a really powerful tool called Regular Expressions (regex). I encourage you to play with it, because it's a really powerful tool in the hands of RPA developer.

To replace the second space in any string with a "." you can use the following action.

```
Object: Utility - Strings
Action: Regex - Find and Replace
Input:
 Regex Pattern: "(?<= .*) "
 Text:          "John B Smith"
 Replacement:   "."
```

The above action is not a standard Blueprism one, so it has to be added to your VBO. The action looks as follows:

[image]

The VB.net code for that action is as follows:

```
Dim R as New Regex(Regex_Pattern, RegexOptions.SingleLine)
Dim M as Match = R.Match(Text)
replacement_result = R.Replace(Text,Regex_Pattern,replacement_string)
```

There might be a need for some additional assemblies, so please see below a printscreen of references and namespaces used in my object:
[image]

Comment: Thanks! I have the utility Strings object, but I don't have this action?

Comment: Thanks! I'm getting one error saying that replacement_string is not declared. Would you know how to fix that?

Comment: Apologies if stupid question, but do you mean I must declare it as an input?

Comment: Yes, to use variables in the code stage, you need to pass them from the process, to the object and then to the exact code stage. By setting a variable as an input to the code stage, you are declaring a variable of that type. That variable is something you will be able then use in your code. In that code stage there are 3 input string variables (Text,Regex_Pattern,replacementI_string) and one output string variable (replacement_result). I am sure you can get that to work!

Comment: Thanks, it is running now for me however the output is John B.Smith and should be John.BSmith ? I have tried reversing the regex pattern which did nothing for me.

Answer (score 0):

I think the simplest solution would be

```
 Replace(Replace(Text,"  "," ")" ","."))
```

if you know that it will give one or two spaces 
First replace the two white spaces to single and then again single white space to dot(.)